# USB Hard Drive Mounted On Tomato Router Does Not Return HD Space Remaining or Number Of Files

Tags: hard-drive, router, tomato, ntfs-3g

Devices:

- Netgear R7000 with Shibby Tomato Firmware 1.28.0000 -132 K26ARM USB AIO-64K
- WD MyBook 6TB USB Hard Drive mounted as 'fuseblk' device on my router.
- Multiple LAN Windows 10 Computers on a WorkGroup.

I can access--R/W--the data on the HD using Windows Explorer without any problem. However, the Properties dropdown in Windows Explorer shows both 'Used Space' and 'Free Space' to be '0'. There is no information about number of files either.

Several windows programs error-out because they cannot get access to the amount of free space on this HD. None of the alternate programs to copy files to/from this HD function properly.

The router uses 'Open NTFS-3G' driver to mount the USB HD. It is my hope that this driver is responsible and that I can add switches to make it function differently. The router has 'before mount' and 'after mount' fields to accomplish this, if possible.

I don't 'speak' linux, but can get by with cheat sheets and the Telnet Daemon in my router, if that helps.

Thanks, Jim